# How to save several data sets into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, plugins, prompt, krpano

I try to write a plugin for krpano in JavaScript.

The actual problem I have is to store several datasets the right way so that it can be accessed easily later on.

I have a number of rendered panoramic images (changes from project to project, 1-10max) which can have some variations of it. There can be variations with other flooring, other colours of kitchen, at another daytime and so on. So I don't know in beforehand how many panoramic images there will be and how many variations they have.

My thought was to use `prompt();` to get the information needed from the user and go with a for loop to create all the needed variables.

```
 var panoCount = prompt("How many Panos do you have?");

    for (var i = 0; i < panoCount; i++) {
        panoOptions[i+1] = prompt("How many Options do you have for " + (i+1) + ". pano?");
 }
```

Let's say I have one panoramic image with 2 different floors, 2 different types of furniture and 2 different daytimes. We get a total amount of 8 Pictures (2*2*2).

In that case, we get:

```
 How many Panos do you have? 
 -> 1 (store to panoCount)

 How many Options do you have for 1. pano? 
 -> 3 (floors, furniture, daytime)
```

Now I want another `prompt();` in the for loop to get asked how many variants I have for each option (variants of floors, variants of furniture, variants of daytime) and how the are named. (Daytime, Nighttime f.ex.)

What is the best way to store all that data in JavaScript. Should I use arrays in an array or is there a better solution?

Further explanations of task:
In general i want to build a plugin for a html/xml based pano viewer than can handle versions of a pano. so there will be menus in the pano where you can f.ex. change the floor and it will load the new pano or change the url of the existing pano to the new one.

Comment: Questions that are looking for "best way to do x" are opinion-based and hence not on topic on stackoverflow. Could you please rephrase the requirements? What do you expect of the storage? It's not clear what you want to achieve by storing something the "right way so that it can be accessed easily later on".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's quite complicated for me as I don't know exactly where to start and which way is the best to get that all running in the end. I did some further explanations above to my task.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way than another to answer your question. It all depends on the way you implement your requirements in the end.

But, if I can help, I suggest you use array of Objects to store your data as it is easy and comprehensive to access a specific piece of data:

```
var myPanoSet = [
    {
        panoName: "MyPano1",
        options: {
            floor: [...],
            furniture: [...],
            daytime: [...]
        }
    }
};
```

Then you can access your data with a readable query like:

```
myPanoSet[0].options['floor'].count; // How many floor I have for first pano.
```

But it is all up to you...

Regards,